# Lucrehulk outer ring thickness

Tags: star-wars

In the prequel trilogy, *Lucrehulk*-class ships ring sections were essentially toruses. What's the inner diameter of the ring section?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you need this info for?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I have a RPG character owning a corporation that intends to build Lucrehulks as freighters: the character's corporation has adjustable orbital drydocks capable of building starship sections that are at most 1km wide or high. With the answer below I know it will be doable with these slipways under the character's possession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image at [Wookieepedia for the ship](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lucrehulk-class_battleship), and using a pixel measurement, the inner radius averages half the distance to the outer radius. Since the diameter is listed as roughly 3 km, thst argues that the inner diameter will be about 1.5 km.

[image: Lucrehulk image]

If you're instead looking for the thickness of the donut, that works out as 1.5 - 0.75 = 0.75 km.

I get the same ratios for measurements made on the blueprints.

[image: Lucrehulk blueprints]

The blueprints suggest that the torus is not symmetrical, so both forms of diameter will vary along the length of the ship.